# Trouble with .erase() in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, erase

I am building a games library and I want the user to be able to delete games.
I am trying to use the .erase() function but i am making a mistake somewhere.
I am studying my code for days and i can't find a anwser.
Why? Beceause I am just 15 and don't have that programming mind every other programmer has. That's why i don't call myself a programmer but just an ambiteuse teenager. Please help me. (Sorry for my spelling)

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator myIterator;
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;             
                                            vector<string> games;                                
    games.push_back("Crysis2");
    games.push_back("GodOfWar3");
    games.push_back("FIFA12");

    cout <<"Welcome to your Games Library.\n";
    cout <<"\nWarning!!! Don't type spaces, put ecerything together!!!\n";
    cout <<"\nThese are your games:\n";
    for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout <<*iter <<endl;
    }
    //the loop!
    string action;
    string newGame;

    cout <<"\n-Type 'exit' if you want to quit.\n-Type 'add' if you want to add a game.\n-Type 'delete' if you want to delete a game.\n-Type 'find' if you want to search a game.\n-Type 'game' if you don't know what game to play. ";

    while (action != "exit")
    {


        cout <<"\n\nWhat do you want to do: ";
        cin >> action;


        if (action == "add")
        {
            cout <<"\nType the name of the game you want to add: ";
            cin >> newGame;

            games.push_back(newGame);

            for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
            {
                cout <<*iter <<endl;
            }

            continue;
        }
        else if (action == "delete")
        {
            cout <<"Type the name of the game you want to delete: ";
            cin >> newGame;

            iter = find(games.begin(), games.end(), newGame);

            if(iter != games.end())
            {
                games.erase(newGame);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"\nGame not found.";
            }

            continue;
        }
        else if (action == "find")
        {
            cout <<"Which game you want to look for in your library: ";
            cin >> newGame;

            iter = find(games.begin(), games.end(), newGame);

            if (iter != games.end())
            {
                cout << "Game found.\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Game not found.\n";
            }

            continue;
        }
        else if (action == "game")
        {
            srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
            random_shuffle(games.begin(), games.end());
            cout << "\nWhy don't you play " <<games[0];

            continue;
        }
        else if (action == "quit")
        {
            cout <<"\nRemember to have fun while gaming!!\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"\nCommand not found";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would help if you could include the definition of 'games' and 'newgame'.

Comment: We'd need to see some more code. You also haven't described the problem you're getting. Does it compile? What happens when you run it?

Comment: You need to paste larger piece of code. We don't know what `games` is (vector? list?). Block ends with `continue` - what loop are you continuing there? How do you know you are making a mistake? What is the problem you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`erase()` takes an iterator (in this case, the result of `find`, which is `iter`), not a string (like `newGame`).

Comment: You not only said what was wrong but also why, thank you very much dude!

Answer (score 4):

You are just passing the wrong parameter to erase. The code

```
if(iter != games.end())
{
    games.erase(newGame);
}
```

Should be

```
if(iter != games.end())
{
    games.erase(iter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me allot. I didn't pick you as the answer beceause i see you have a big reputation, and @jpm told me why my code was wrong. But still thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Stijn - That's fine. It's your choice of the answer you like the most. And you are right, I already have more points than needed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
iterator erase ( iterator position );
iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last );
```

Try replacing `games.erase(newGame);` with `games.erase(iter);`